# IP address for Google Cloud Messaging server

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm about to roll out an implementation of GCM on a server and need to open the appropriate firewalls by IP.

Does anyone know where I can find the IP address range for android.googleapis.com ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found that the IP ranges for android.googleapis.com are not published.

Comment: if the ports are opened for the dns android.googleapis.com on proxy firewall will it work fine and allow device to use GCM on proxy instead of Open 3g or 4g network ?

Answer (score 2):

According to https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http:

> GCM doesn't provide specific IPs, so you should allow your firewall to
>   accept outgoing connections to all IP addresses contained in the IP
>   blocks listed in Google's ASN of 15169.

And [a ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/535936/configuring-firewall-for-google-cloud-messaging-asn-15169) links to the following lists of IP ranges contained within ASN 15169:

- IPv4: http://bgp.he.net/AS15169#_prefixes
- IPv6: http://bgp.he.net/AS15169#_prefixes6

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be what you want, but you can just run "nslookup android.googleapis.com" from cmd (Windows) or bash (*nix). My results are:

```
nslookup android.googleapis.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.130

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    googleapis.l.google.com
Addresses:  2001:4860:b007::5f
          74.125.142.95
Aliases:  android.googleapis.com
```