# Android App cannot show the push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have problem with several Android device, I'm using the same apps in 4 Android device. But only one device receive the notification. After seeing the network packets, I discover that 1 device got PSH ACK from IP 173.194.72.188 (I guess its Google's IP) and it did received the notification. Although the other 3 devices also got PSH ACK from IP 64.233.187.188 (I guess its also Google's IP) but it didn't show in the notification display. What could be the problem with the notification from this IP 64.233.187.188? Or something wrong with my other 3 device? Any advice?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: For the IP related issue of GCM, you can refer to here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396234/ip-range-of-google-gcm-push-notification-server