# Proxy Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

On my office, the wifi using proxy to limit access to internet. When my tablet using that wifi. the message from my server (using GCM Push Notification) never receipt by my tablet.

i think i need some exception address to set on my proxy so my tablet can receive the message from server.

Can anyone give me the list of exception address to set on my server proxy ?

Thank You

*sorry for my english.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do here.  If you are trying to get an app to run on your network that is a better question for [Server fault](https://serverfault.com/).  If you are writing a program that needs to configure itself to run on the network, then please provide more details and code.

Comment: i just want to know what address using by GCM to receive message  on my tablet from GCM server. so i can add the address to my server proxy to add on exception list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is addressed in the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http#message-with-payload--data-message):

> If your organization has a firewall that restricts the traffic to or
>   from the Internet, you need to configure it to allow connectivity with
>   GCM in order for your GCM client apps to receive messages. The ports
>   to open are: 5228, 5229, and 5230. GCM typically only uses 5228, but
>   it sometimes uses 5229 and 5230. GCM doesn't provide specific IPs, so
>   you should allow your firewall to accept outgoing connections to all
>   IP addresses contained in the IP blocks listed in Google's ASN of
>   15169.

This is also addressed in another SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396234/ip-range-of-google-gcm-push-notification-server).